# Geb NoClassDefFoundError: geb/error/UnableToLoadException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, geb

I've ben having trouble setting up and testing Geb.
I have a simple Groovy script:

```
import geb.Browser;

println("Test 11")

Browser.drive {
    go "http://www.google.com"
}
```

and I always get the following error:

```
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: geb/error/UnableToLoadException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: geb/error/UnableToLoadException
    at geb.Browser.<init>(Browser.groovy:61)
    at geb.Browser.drive(Browser.groovy:1028)
    at geb.Browser$drive.call(Unknown Source)
    at Main.run(Main.groovy:8)
```

I wrote a `Class.forName("geb.error.UnableToLoadException")` which changed the error to

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: geb/error/GebException
    at Main.run(Main.groovy:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: geb.error.GebException
    ... 1 more
```

It seems to me that Geb is searching for a class `GebException`, which is **not** inside the `geb-core-2.1.jar` I've downloaded! Next to this jar, I also added the `selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar`. Am I doing something wrong? Did I install some wrong geb-core library? I am using IntelliJ IDEA as the IDE. Thank you for your help

Best regards

Comment: I think GebException is not in that jar (geb-core-2.1.jar). It would be great if you can refactor the code to not use that class as in the latest geb core jar, that class is not there. You can check it here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgebjunit405jar.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now the error is that is cannot find geb/waiting/Wait. Is there another jar that contains this "Wait"-file?

Comment: You can download the following which has the required jar -> http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgebwaiting091jar.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a maven project where yourfile is in, I suggest to check your dependency list in pom.xml first.

As I tested in my env, it is executing perfectly